# WebAuthBroker can't connect to service, but hand-posting in IE is succesful

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I have a Windows 8 app that builds a string and posts to https: using WebAuthBroker.  Relevant code is below.

The problem is that WebAuthBroker takes this URI and cannot connect, but when I hand=post this URI into IE, it works fine.

Running VS2012 on Windows 8.
In Package.appmanifest, have enabled Enterprise Authentication, Internet(Client), Internet(Client&Server), Private Networks(Client & Server), and Shared User Certificates.

```
            async Task AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var requestUriStr = string.Format("{0}?client_id={1}&response_type=token&redirect_uri={2}", logonUriString, clientId, redirectUriString);

        requestUriStr += "&scope=stream";

        var requestUri = new Uri(requestUriStr, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        var redirectUri = new Uri(redirectUriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        var result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, requestUri, redirectUri);

        if (result.ResponseStatus != WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
        {
            throw new Exception("Login failed: " + result.ResponseErrorDetail);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my problem.  From: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/13d3742d-4b6b-444e-840e-a4db11462a08

> Turns out that if you use Fiddler to debug your HTTP requests, it will
>   make WebAuthenticationBroker stop working. This may or may not be
>   related to the "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" options provided in this app,
>   but as soon as I closed Fiddler, WebAuthenticationBroker started
>   working again. I can replicate the bug at will by starting Fiddler
>   again, and resolve the problem by closing it.
>
> I didn't make advanced researches as whether or not enabling or
>   disabling the HTTPS options of Fiddler will impact the use of the
>   WebAuthenticationBroker class and methods, but on first sight it looks
>   like barely disabling HTTPS will make it working again. I usually
>   close it personally to be on the safer side.

So I had Fiddler open the whole time I was writing / debugging.  I closed Fiddler, and it worked the first time!